# Sequelize createdAt and updatedAt timestamps are wrong

Tags: timezone, timestamp, sequelize.js, momentjs, sequelize-cli

I created a table with timestamps using sequelize. when I am updating the table, it automatically updates the timestamp (i.e createdAt and updatedAt). but these times are different from my local time. I have attached herewith 2 screenshots with the model script if I use moment to convert timezone like this use`updateddAt: moment().utc(new Date())` it works fine. is there a way to automatically update the timestamps with current timezone?

```
    'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('States', {

      hashCode: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
          unique:true,
          autoIncrement:false
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('States');
  }
};
```

when updateding the table
[image]

my local time in the pc
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Create database like this you'll get automatically created at updated at according local time

`const sequelize = new Sequelize("db_name", "username", "password", 
{
  logging: false,
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "mysql",
  dialectOptions: {
    // useUTC: false, //for reading from database
    dateStrings: true,
    typeCast: true,
    timezone: "+05:30"
  },
  timezone: "+05:30", //for writing to database
  operatorsAliases: false
});`

Comment: I am using the v6 version of sequelize and the docs state this:

```timezone: The timezone configured on the MySQL server. This is used to type cast server date/time values to JavaScript Date object and vice versa. This can be 'local', 'Z', or an offset in the form +HH:MM or -HH:MM. (Default: 'local')```

So your answer points to the correct attribute to set but the value will cause an error, at least in v6 and onwards, using `+00:00` has done the trick for me

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#connection-options

Answer (score 5):

You should set the `timezone` property in sequelize options:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: 'db_name',
  username: 'username',
  password: null,
  dialect: 'mysql'
  timezone: 'utc', // your timezone comes here, ex.: 'US/Hawaii'
});
```

Comment: then I get this error 
throw new Error('Setting a custom timezone is not supported by SQLite, dates are always returned as UTC. Please remove the custom timezone parameter.');

Comment: and what if you try this: `dialectOptions: {
    useUTC: false,
},`

Comment: no luck, currently dialectOptions are only supported for 'mysql', 'postgres', 'mssql'

Comment: Is anyone using 'mariadb' as dialect with a European timezone please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm late but this works for me: 
    new Sequelize(db,user,pass, {timezone: "-05:00"}) where "-05:00" is offset time.

En 
config.json too...

```
{
"development": {
"database": "db",
"username": "user",
"password": "pwd",
"logging": false, // verbose
"host": "localhost",
"dialect": "mysql",
"operatorsAliases": false, 
"timezone": "-05:00"
},
"test": {
...
},  
"production": {
...
```

}
    }